# Attach .mdf file to a remote database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a `.mdf` file stored in local.

I work remotely on server through ssms. I am in need to restore the `.mdf` file. Is it possible to attach such file to remotely working server?

Comment: Avoid using the word "restore" because that refers to backup/restore, a different operation completely (because you *can* restore a SQL Server backup from a network share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends on your SKU (ironically, more expensive versions are less capable).

- SQL Server Standard / Enterprise: Yes, but but you can only use `CREATE DATABASE` with the DB path specified as a network share, which means:

  - You need `CREATE DATABASE` permission on the server (e.g. be an administrator or be assigned that right).
  - The network share needs appropriate ACLs for both NTFS and SMB for the user-account which the SQL Server is using.
  - The `AttachDbFilename` option is not supported by SQL Server Standard or Enterprise, only Express.
- SQL Server LocalDb: No. LocalDb only works locally. The clue's in the name.
- SQL Server Express: Maybe.

  - You can use the same `CREATE DATABASE` command as Standard Edition.
  - While you can use `AttachDbFilename` this only works for local files, you cannot specify a UNC share: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5adeef5-93e5-409c-b476-238e2f6dfcd2/how-to-connect-database-from-shared-drive-in-c?forum=csharplanguage

So your only option for mounting an `*.mdf` remotely is to use a network share and to attach it using `CREATE DATABASE`, you cannot use `AttachDbFilename`.

Note that performance will be poor because SQL Server can't use the magic tricks it uses to obtain low-level disk access for faster IO.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/

Answer (score 0):

No, using ssms it is not possible.Either you can generate database scripts or upload the .mdf file on the remote db using your hosting admin panel and restore from there.